# Is .x-form-arrow-trigger css class used only for down arrow image on ComboBox?

Tags: extjs

In ExtJS is .x-form-arrow-trigger css class used only for down arrow image on ComboBox or there are some other places where this class can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ocasionally found in documentation for Ext.form.ComboBox

Section *Configs*:

**triggerClass** : String

An additional CSS class used to style the trigger button. **The trigger will always get the class 'x-form-trigger'** and triggerClass will be appended if specified (**defaults to 'x-form-arrow-trigger'** which displays a downward arrow icon).
Defaults to: "x-form-arrow-trigger"

Answer (score 1):

Given that the only style rule for this class is a background image pointing to this file...

http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.0.7-gpl/resources/themes/images/default/boundlist/trigger-arrow.png

...then you can safely assume that it is only used where a down arrow trigger is implemented (and to my knowledge that is only on the combobox component - someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I use older version of ExtJs where  .x-form-arrow-trigger mentioned only in js code without any style rules in css. But thanks for responce, now I will count that this class uses only in ComboBox.